# Issue in Deploy flutter web app into firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter

I deploy the flutter web app into firebase as https://flutter-explained.dev/blog/flutter-web-to-firebase-hosting/
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1PXs.png)

I met this when call deployed url "https://save-recipes.web.app"
Will you let me know in detail how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
flutter build web
sudo firebase init
firebase deploy
```

Is this the order you followed?

In `firebase init` select `Hosting: Configure files for Firebase Hosting and (optionally) set up GitHub Action deploys`

```
> What do you want to use as your public directory? build/web
> Configure as a single-page app (rewrite all urls to /index.html)? Yes
> Set up automatic builds and deploys with GitHub? No
> File build/web/index.html already exists. Overwrite? No
```

Then you would get

```
> Skipping write of build/web/index.html
> Writing configuration info to firebase.json...
> Writing project information to .firebaserc...
> ✔  Firebase initialization complete!
```

Then run `firebase deploy`

```
=== Deploying to 'firebaseProjectName'...
```

and it would run the following

```
i  deploying hosting
i  hosting[firebaseProjectName]: beginning deploy...
i  hosting[firebaseProjectName]: found 25 files in build/web
✔  hosting[firebaseProjectName]: file upload complete
i  hosting[firebaseProjectName]: finalizing version...
✔  hosting[firebaseProjectName]: version finalized
i  hosting[firebaseProjectName]: releasing new version...
✔  hosting[firebaseProjectName]: release complete
```

✔  Deploy complete!

```
Project Console: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/firebaseProjectName/overview
Hosting URL: https://firebaseProjectName.web.app
```

If it still doesn't work, try these following

```
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

or

```
firebase deploy --except functions
```

Let me know how it goes...